# check file icon in project tree using SWT Bot eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, junit4, swtbot

I m testing a eclipse plugin using swt bot.but I cant find a way to check the icon of a file in the tree in project explorer.How can this be done

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using this ?

```
 tree.display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Image i = treeItem.widget.getImage();   
        }
    });
```